# json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type hexutil.Uint

Tags: go-ethereum

I am following the ethereum-development-with-go book and have bumped into an issue.
The data is from a successful transction:

> https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xcd25e4f8afcbc498bee5923a59336de4af5b8bd6c5dd274374e7ff2089c94169

This is the offending code snippet:

```
    blockHash := common.HexToHash("0xcd25e4f8afcbc498bee5923a59336de4af5b8bd6c5dd274374e7ff2089c94169")
    count, err := client.TransactionCount(context.Background(), blockHash)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("blockHash = %T\n", blockHash)
        fmt.Println(blockHash)
        log.Fatal(whereami.WhereAmI(), err)
    }
```

Which gives me the output:

```
blockHash = common.Hash
0xcd25e4f8afcbc498bee5923a59336de4af5b8bd6c5dd274374e7ff2089c94169
2023/04/22 15:00:34 File: transactions.go  Function: main.transactions Line: 60json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type hexutil.Uint
```

Any idea how I can solve this?

Below is the full code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/jimlawless/whereami"
    "log"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
)

func transactions() {
    fmt.Println(whereami.WhereAmI())
    blockNumber := big.NewInt(3340122)
    block, err := client.BlockByNumber(context.Background(), blockNumber)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(whereami.WhereAmI(), err)
    }
    numTransactions := 0
    for _, tx := range block.Transactions() {
        numTransactions++
        fmt.Println("numTransactions: ", numTransactions)
        fmt.Println(tx.Hash().Hex())
    
        chainID, err := client.NetworkID(context.Background())
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(whereami.WhereAmI(), err)
        }
        fmt.Println(chainID)

        if from, err := types.Sender(types.NewEIP155Signer(chainID), tx); err == nil {
            fmt.Println(from.Hex())
        }

        receipt, err := client.TransactionReceipt(context.Background(), tx.Hash())
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(whereami.WhereAmI(), err)
        }

        fmt.Println(receipt.Status) // 1
    }

    blockHash := common.HexToHash("0xcd25e4f8afcbc498bee5923a59336de4af5b8bd6c5dd274374e7ff2089c94169")
    count, err := client.TransactionCount(context.Background(), blockHash)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("blockHash = %T\n", blockHash)
        fmt.Println(blockHash)
        log.Fatal(whereami.WhereAmI(), err)
    }

    for idx := uint(0); idx < count; idx++ {
        tx, err := client.TransactionInBlock(context.Background(), blockHash, idx)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(whereami.WhereAmI(), err)
        }

        fmt.Println(tx.Hash().Hex()) // 0x5d49fcaa394c97ec8a9c3e7bd9e8388d420fb050a52083ca52ff24b3b65bc9c2
    }

    txHash := common.HexToHash("0x5d49fcaa394c97ec8a9c3e7bd9e8388d420fb050a52083ca52ff24b3b65bc9c2")
    tx, isPending, err := client.TransactionByHash(context.Background(), txHash)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(whereami.WhereAmI(), err)
    }

    fmt.Println(tx.Hash().Hex()) // 0x5d49fcaa394c97ec8a9c3e7bd9e8388d420fb050a52083ca52ff24b3b65bc9c2
    fmt.Println(isPending)       // false
}
```